# What is the best Git repository for sharing code only with paying customers in a commercial project?

Tags: git, version-control, github, repository, hosting

We're releasing a commercial project in the near future. The plan is to give to the paying users permission to access the project source. Wiki and issue tracking should be preferably free for everyone to see, but that wouldn't be a problem if I was forced to keep it private too.

I know `GitHub` private repositories and I really like it, but I'm not sure if it would allow me to add every customer as a collaborator. I am also interested in knowing if this approach I'm describing is the best for the scenario I described.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GitHub is perfect for that, look at Unreal Engine 4's recent "[Open Source for Customers](https://www.unrealengine.com/ue4-on-github)" approach.

When you give Epic your github username, they automatically add you to their github "Organisation". They have the project there as a private repo, and now I have access to read and clone it.

If I clone it, I have my own private repo copy of it I can work on, and submit pull requests.

I don't believe you need Enterprise to have this feature, if you check their [plans](https://github.com/pricing) you can see:

> Collaborators may fork any private repository you’ve added them to
>   without their own paid plan. Their forks do not count against your
>   private repository quota.

Comment: That's actually a pretty good example. The problem is that I'm not sure if I would need a github enterprise account, because it costs 5000 USD per year. Would this work if a normal private rep?

Comment: Updated answer, don't think you need enterprise to do this.

Comment: You are right.. I just checked and I can create an "Organization" starting from 25 USD a month which is quite payable. The advantage of having an organization is that I can fine grain permissions and give the paying users only the ability to download the source code and create pull requests. Thank you.

Comment: Enterprise is for hosting the repository in your own infrastructure. That's how it's extremely expensive

Answer (score 0):

so if you want to have the full control of your git repositories,my advices is build your own git repositories manage system:

1. [GitHub Enterprise](https://enterprise.github.com/),available in pre-build ova Virtual Machine format,easy to use and try it free.
2. [stash from Atlassian](https://www.atlassian.com/software/stash),another choice should be considered,also you can try it for free.

Comment: Github for enterprise costs 5000 USD a year! o.O

Comment: Stash also is extremely costy for large number of users =/

Answer (score 0):

BitBucket has an entirely different [pricing plan](https://bitbucket.org/plans) you might prefer.

It's every bit as good as GitHub, but lacking the "community" aspect.

Also, free private repo's!